# Including a PHP file within PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, include

I have a website which is running a PHP if statement to show content based on the type of file attached, i.e. Jpg, Txt, MP4.

So my code for showing TXT files is:

```
if($post_attachment == 'txt'){$display_attachment = "

        <div class=\"sectionDivide\"></div>
        <div class=\"section\">
            <div class=\"articleAttachment\">
                include(\"../a/files/attachments/$post_year/$post_month/$post_id.$post_attachment\");
            </div>
        </div>

    ";}
```

The problem is that it's not displaying the content of the TXT file, but instead showing the line `include("../a/files/attachments/2016/11/161123095119.txt");` in my web page.

How can I get it to display the content of the text file where I echo out `$display_attachment`?

Comment: Use actual concatenation for the include, not interpolation which won't work.

Comment: The issue is that you are not using an include command, but instead write _the string_ "include(...)" into your code. How should php _guess_ that you want that interpreted as a command?

Comment: How exactly does `concatenation` work in my code sample? I have no idea what it is?

Comment: @arkascha, so what would be the sollution here?

Comment: If you don't know what concatenation is then I'd recommend reading some PHP tutorials before trying to go any further.

Comment: @JonStirling - I'm not interested in reading a load of conflicting tutorials, I just want a solution so I can upload the website.

Comment: Then good luck to you.

Comment: @JonStirling So even though you know a sollution, you're not going to give it in an answer?

Comment: Correct. We're not here to do people's work for them because they don't want to learn, or don't want to put time / effort into the problem. Or at least that's my view on SO.

Comment: @JonStirling - The way I see it is I've built a fully functional website, and have spent years learning web development, and now I've run into a small problem, people like you tell us we should Learn more. I'm past learning all the changes, I just want to run a website.

Comment: @WD If that's the case, then I'm unsure how you could have done so without learning about string concatenation as it's one of the very basics of programming in many different languages. Either way, arkascha has given you the answer you need.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate (and crude) way is to use php's string concatenation operator (`.`):

```
$display_attachment = sprintf('
        <div class="sectionDivide"></div>
        <div class="section">
            <div class="articleAttachment">' . 
    include("/some/path/to/file") . '
            </div>
        </div>
');
```

---

A somewhat less chaotic, though still not really readable variant is the use of `sprintf()`:

```
$display_attachment = sprintf('
        <div class="sectionDivide"></div>
        <div class="section">
            <div class="articleAttachment">
%s
            </div>
        </div>
',
    include("/some/path/to/file")
);
```

---

A clean solution would fetch the result of the inclusion into a string variable and use that.

Answer (score -1):

To display the content of a File `include()` is the wrong function. `include()`will load and execute php-code.

You should try to use `fread()` instead to get the content of a TXT-file: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: Include will work perfectly fine, even for non-PHP code.